# Spectrum of a convolution operator

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $T$ be the operator from $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ to $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ that is given by $Tf := f * g$ where $g$ is in $L^2$.

How do I now find that the spectrum of $T$ is equal to the essential range of $\hat{g}$? How is the spectrum of $T$ related to the invertibility of the operator $G\hat{f} = \hat{f}\hat{g}$?

The hat denotes the Fourier transform.

Comment: It is interesting if for some function $a$ we consider the operator
$Tf:= (af)*g$. Can we still find the spectrum of this operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$
conjugates $T$ to the multiplication
operator $S:h\mapsto\hat g h$ (i.e. $\mathcal{F}(f\ast g)=\hat g\mathcal{F}(f)$).
Hence $T$ and $S$ have the same spectrum.

Comment: Then you use that $UAU^*$ and $A$ have the same spectrum. Okay.

Comment: Jonas, does that work in an infinite dimensional space?